# Can a mathematical proof always be objectively determined as correct or incorrect?

Tags: philosophy, proof-theory, riemann-hypothesis, mathematicians

Fields medalist [Michael Atiyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Atiyah) claimed a simple proof of the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis), but [many mathematicians rejected his proof](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2180504-riemann-hypothesis-likely-remains-unsolved-despite-claimed-proof/). Am I right in saying that Atiyah's proof is either objectively correct (then why did many mathematicians reject it?) or objectively incorrect (then as one of the leading mathematicians, Atiyah failed to find his own mistake(s)). Or is it possible that the truthfulness of Atiyah's proof cannot be determined?

So my question is,

> In a certain axiomatic system, can a mathematical proof always be objectively determined as correct or incorrect? Or is it possible that there exists a proof to a result such that the truthfulness of the proof cannot be determined?

Here I am not considering the cases such as the proof contains typos or gramatical mistakes which can easily be fixed.

Comment: Proofs are always considered correct or incorrect relative to some standard.  Many proofs from the 18th century would be not be considered proofs by modern standards of rigor.  But it is possible to define an absolute standard by which all proofs could be judged - you check them by computer.  However, very few mathematicians want to go to the trouble of writing down their proofs in computer-checkable form, so until that changes there will be some amount of ambiguity in what proofs are considered acceptable.

Comment: "Objectively" means "agreed by the community of mathematicians". As per comemnt above, in the middle/long run "standards" of *proofs* evolve.

Answer (score 1):

If you completely formalize the statement and the proof, it can be, in principle , checked automatically, whether the given proof shows the given statement. This is also true for computer proofs because they must have a finite running time. This does however not at all mean that such a verification can be done in a reasonable time.

A SIMPLE proof of the Riemann hypoethesis is so unlikely, that I heavily doubt every such proof whoever claims to have found it.

Comment: Sure. I do not doubt Atiyah's mathematical ability, nor do I doubt his honesty, thus I find his claim of his simple proof puzzling.

Comment: Even Andrew Wiles made a mistake in the first attempt to prove Fermat's last theorem, he needed a year to correct it. There is noone that cannot make a mistake in a mathematical proof. Even more weird is the claimed proof of the abc-conjecture that apparently noone understands.

Answer (score -1):

For proofs on paper one should always be able to check if its objectively correct.

The situation is different if its a computer proof such as the four-color problem. Here a program checks all the possible cases. Its hard for the individual to check if its objectively correct. At least, its questionable.

Comment: I agree that checking computer proof can be hard, but it should be theoretically possible (let $t\to\infty$). Even if it takes $3,000,000$ years to check, I will still consider the proof can be determined as being objectively correct (or incorrect).